# Sync Excel file from a network folder to PDA with windows mobile via wireless

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, windows-mobile

How can I send a file from a network folder to a pda with windos mobile?? is a excel file that I want to share with hand held.

Any help will be granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with built-in software.
Fire up your devices File Explorer app and tap Menu.
Top "Go To ->" then "Open Path" and then "New Path..."

Enter the UNC location of your file share (\serverName\ShareName)

Browse!